# Надо ли выделить запятыми "на первый взгляд"?

Tags: вводные-слова

> ...способствовало усложнению ряда концептуальных положений, что вызывало полемику касательно частных, на первый взгляд, моментов, таких, например, как...

Надо ли выделить запятыми "на первый взгляд"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в приведённом примере - типичное вводное, да и затесалось меж словами так, что просится его обособить. Но в правительственных корректорских 70–80-х (к примеру), куда брали только филфаковцев, было заведено: *на первый взгляд* -  в отличие от *мой, твой, его* - без запятых.

[**НА ПЕРВЫЙ ВЗГЛЯД,** *вводное сочетание*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_441)

> То же, что «как сперва показалось». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных
>   словах и сочетаниях см. в [Прил. 2](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).
>
> *Особенно некрасиво, **на первый взгляд**, во всей этой рулеточной сволочи было то уважение к занятию, та серьезность и даже
>   почтительность, с которыми все обступали столы.* Ф. Достоевский,
>   Игрок. *Это незначительное, **на первый взгляд**, событие, как сейчас
>   убедятся наши читатели, неожиданно привело к серьезному перелому в
>   настроениях и мечтаниях старика Хоттабыча.* Л. Лагин, Старик Хоттабыч.
>   ***На первый взгляд*** – ничего особенного, костюм такой вроде водолазного и шлем как у водолаза, с большим окном впереди. А. и Б.
>   Стругацкие, Пикник на обочине.
>
> **! Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «вначале» или «по первому впечатлению»).
>
> Уже ***на первый взгляд*** можно было отличить, что это не якут, хотя
>   одет он был по-якутски. В. Короленко, Соколинец. *Он был дурен собой
>   **на первый взгляд**, белые льняные волосы прямо падали с головы странной формы, бледный лицом, с белыми ресницами и несколько
>   косившимися глазами.* А. Герцен, Доктор Крупов. *Да и вправду,
>   смотрите, в самом деле, как **на первый взгляд** всё между нами
>   холодно, угрюмо, точно сердито...* Ф. Достоевский, Белые ночи.
>
> @ Зачастую трудно определить, является ли сочетание «на первый взгляд»
>   вводным. В спорных случаях решение о постановке знаков препинания
>   принимает автор текста.